# How to Globally turn of SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services data caching

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I am new to this version of reporting services. I did some research and found off of Microsoft's website:

**To set report caching options**

1. Point to a report in the library.
2. Click the down arrow, and select Manage processing options.
3. In Data Refresh Options, click Use cached data. If you see "This report can not be cached because one or more of the data sources credentials are not stored", the report is not configured to run unattended and you must modify the data sources to use stored credentials before setting this option. For instructions, see How to: Schedule Report and Subscription Processing (Reporting Services in SharePoint Integrated Mode).
4. In Cache Options, specify how the cache will expire:
5. Enter a number of minutes after which the cache will expire.
6. Use a shared schedule to clear the cache at times specified in the schedule.
7. Create a custom schedule to clear the cache at a time that you specify.

That is all well and good if I didn't have more than a small hand full of reports to do this individually to, but I have at least 20 reports that will get installed to multiple systems so doing this manually each time is not feasible.

What I would like to find out is there a way to either script or some other way to set multiple reports with the cache option set to not cache instead of the default to cache the report for 10080 minutes. This would allow them to be ran on demand. Yes, I realize that Microsoft's intention is to lessen the load on the database, but the nature of the reports that I need to run require them to be ran on demand with the current data in the database and not a previously cached version of the report.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same problem and it turned out to be the report deployment tool we use (RSBuild)  that was setting the cache for each report.  We removed the caching from the deployment config file and redeployed the report and the problem went away.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply as I never got notification on your reply. I looked in the applications config file and found the cachetimeout under the reports section which changes the timeout for all the reports listed. Thanks a lot as I was banging my head against this for a while.